# How i see if email already exist or not in database and any other fields in Django

Tags: django-models, django-forms, modelform

i am beginnner in django. Can anyone help me to filter data from the database? I am using ModelForm for the registration system. which code I can add to filter out is email already exists or not
forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import AccountNew
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

class NewUser(ModelForm):
        model = AccountNew
        fields = '__all__'


views.py

    from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import NewUser

# Create your views here.
def register(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = NewUser(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Account = form.save()
            # Do something with the author (model instance)
            return render(response, 'message.html',{'form': form})
        else:
            return render(response, 'register.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form = NewUser()
        return render(response, 'register.html', {'form': form})

model.py

    from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class AccountNew(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField( max_length=50)
    email= models.EmailField( max_length=254)
    id_card = models.IntegerField()
    Transcript_No = models.IntegerField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

can anyone help me? How i can check email or ID card is already register

Answer (score 0):

You would need to filter for the email or ID. For example:

AccountNew.objects.filter(email__iexact='sample@email.com')
AccountNew.objects.filter(id_card__iexact='sample@email.com')

Note that the model field is followed by a double underscore and filter would return a Queryset of results. You can also set unique=True in your model field to ensure that the email/card ID would be unique and Django would do the check for you.

You can check all types of fields lookups here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups